# How can mock repository.findAll().stream().map{}.filter{}

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm having trouble mocking my unit test. I can only mock findAll, but I am not able to mock findAll along with the other methods, stream, map and filter. What would the correct form of the syntax look like:
whenever(productRerpository.findAll).thenReturn(product)?
Below is my function inside the service class.

````
    fun getProductList(userId: Int?, filter: ProductBaseFilter): List<ProductCompleteDto> {
        val productCompleteDtoList = productRepository.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map { ProductCompleteDtoHelper.fillProductCompleteDto(it, userId, filter) }
            .filter { filter.favorited == null || it.productBase?.userFavorite == filter.favorited }
            .filter { filter.modelYear == null || it.categoryComplete?.categoryBase?.modelYear == filter.modelYear }
            .toList()

        return productCompleteDtoList.ifEmpty { throw ProductNoContentException("No products to be returned.") }
    }```
````

Comment: Can you please add the signature of the findAll method? And show what you've tried? Why do you want to mock out the map/filter steps?

Comment: i need to simulate the map and filter steps because if i don't simulate, i can't get the list return as expected in the test. My repository doesn't have findAll method written